# How to loop an mp3 without gaps in monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

I am wishing to seamlessly loop mp3's for an app written in MonoTouch using the AVAudioPlayer and cannot find any examples on how to achieve this. I have found a great library at http://gamua.com/blog/2012/05/gapless-mp3-audio-on-ios/ however it is written for objective c.

I wish for the audio to continue to play even when the device is locked and have played around with the AudioSession initilizer but failed to have this working also.

I am not able to find examples or libraries to assist in achieving results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For queuing up songs without any spaces in between, make sure to use `AVQueuePlayer`, it allows you to pre-load songs. If you just want to loop the same song, just set `NumberOfLoops` to 0 on `AVAudioPlayer` and it will loop forever.

For playing audio in the background, you also need to declare `UIBackgroundModes` in your `Info.plist`.  See this guy's article [here](http://www.sagorin.org/2011/11/29/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/). He's using Obj-C, but you should be able to port his code to MonoTouch.